# How to deal with a a xml file with hyphens using a perl parsing program

Tags: xml, perl

So I'm trying to parse an xml file with the following format ...

```
<message>
<cmd id="result_data">
    <result-file-header>
      <path>PFMD</path>
      <duration>10.56</duration>
      <spectra-count>4</spectra-count>
     </result-file-header>
     <scan-results count="10">
        <scan-result>
               <spectrum-index>4</spectrum-index>
               <scan-index>7</scan-index>
               <time-stamp>13</time-stamp>
               <tic>130e5</tic>
               <start-mass>135</start-mass>
               <stop-mass>500</stop-mass>
               <spectrum count="3">131,45;181,54;240,2</spectrum>
        </scan-result>
        <scan-result>
               <spectrum-index>2</spectrum-index>
               <scan-index>5</scan-index>
               <time-stamp>15</time-stamp>
               <tic>100e5</tic>
               <start-mass>100</start-mass>
               <stop-mass>500</stop-mass>
               <spectrum count="3">131,5;181,6;240,7</spectrum>
         </scan-result>
     </scan-results>
    </cmd>
</message>
```

... using Perl to output the results I want into a text file.

However, I'm having difficulty dealing with the xml names being hyphenated.

Here is the Perl code I'm using

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl-w
 #example to write to text
 my $file = "gapiparseddataexample1.txt";
 unless(open FILE, '>'.$file) {
 die "\nUnable to create $file\n";
 }

use warnings;
use strict;
 use XML::Simple;
 use Data::Dumper;


 my $values= XMLin('samplegapi.xml',KeyAttr=>"scan-result", ForceArray=>'scan-result');       

print Dumper($values);


for my $data(@{$values->{scanresult}}) {
    print FILE "Total Ion Count",":","\n";
    print FILE $data->{tic},"\n";

}
```

Any advice on either how to work around the hyphens (ie replacing them with underscores) is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to put quotes around your hash keys.  So instead of: `$values->{scan-results}` you would say: `$values->{'scan-results'}`.

See also: [Stepping up from XML::Simple to XML::LibXML](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=490846)

**EDIT**

You have the line `print Dumper($values);` in your code.  The output it produces would answer your question (combined with the knowledge that hash keys must be quoted if they contain non-word characters like '-').  If you are unable to interpret the output from Data::Dumper then you need to read the [Perl references tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

I also note that other parts of your code contain random errors that might be the result of cutting and pasting things that you don't understand.  For example, setting the `ForceArray` option to `'scan-result'` is just nonsense.  You either need to set it to `1` or a reference to an array of element names.  Similarly, setting `KeyAttr` to `"scan-result"` makes no sense at all.  These options are documented.

Here's some code that works for me:

```
my $values= XMLin('samplegapi.xml', ForceArray => [ 'scan-result' ]);

my $results = $values->{'cmd'}->{'scan-results'}->{'scan-result'};

for my $data (@$results) {
    print FILE "Total Ion Count",":","\n";
    print FILE $data->{tic},"\n";
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work for me...i think the values from the xml file are not getting initialized for some reason. Any thoughts? I think it has something do to with the multiple start tags in the xml code like the cmd, result-file header, etc.

Comment: thank you so much! worked like a charm! I'm just learning perl right now so its been hard to figure out my errors.